# UIBarButtonItem textures offset when iPhone only app is run on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

In the main view of my app, I instantiate 3 `UIBarButtonItem`(2 actual buttons and 1 flexible spacer) with custom images (created using `[UIImage imageNamed:]`), then set them as the items of a `UIToolBar`. Here's the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIToolbar *menuBar = [UIToolbar new];
    menuBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

    CGRect viewBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

    //menuBar is rotated to be viewed vertically along the right side of the device in portrait orientation, the app does not support device rotation
    menuBar.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(menuBar.transform, M_PI * 0.5f);

    [menuBar setFrame:CGRectMake(viewBounds.size.width - menuBarHeight, 5, menuBarHeight, viewBounds.size.height)];

    [self.view addSubview:menuBar];

    [menuBar release];

    UIBarButtonItem
        *peekButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                       initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"peekIcon.png"]
                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                       target:self
                       action:@selector(peek:)],
        *pauseButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseIcon.png"]
                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                        target:self
                        action:@selector(pauseGame:)],
        *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                      target:nil
                      action:nil];

    menuBar.items = @[flexSpace, pauseButton, peekButton];

    [flexSpace release];
    [pauseButton release];
    [peekButton release];
}
```

When run on a iPod touch running iOS 5.1, the toolBar and buttons appear as expected, like so:

[image]

but when run on an iPad(iOS 4.3), the textures look like this:

[image]

I can not seem to discern the cause, however, I believe it may be an OS, or device specific bug, as I keep encountering similarly obscure graphics issues where UI elements are drawn with total disregard for the underlaying object's data. Unfortunately I can't find any relevant docs (Apple or other wise) to shed some light on this issue.

Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would like to post some images, but apparently I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: I think, you have enough rep to post an image. Try again. :)

Comment: Could you post some code also? That might help us as well.

Comment: Are you using images for both retina and non-retina as image.png and image@2x.png?

Comment: @ABC yes, there are images for retina and non-retina display

Comment: It looks like the images in the first screenshot are distorted (the proportions of the eye look off to me) and that they are correct in the second one, but they're too large to fit in the button. You should probably change your images' sizes.

Comment: Show code! It looks like the wrong images are loading on the iPad, or are being treated as the wrong size. We need to see how you are getting these images and how you are setting these barbuttonitem background images. Also show specifications for the images, i.e. what's the pixel size of the images that are getting loaded on iPad.

Comment: @matt i feel the code is fairly trivial, but since you asked so nicely, I will add it

Comment: Well, my answers didn't help so I deleted them. I can only fall back on what I said before: it looks like the single-resolution images are being loaded when the double-resolution images should be used. Are you sure your image pairs have the right names and the right sizes?

Comment: @matt i seem to have stubbled upon a solution. I will post the answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to arise from calling UINavigationController's method

`-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;`

As screen transitions were not originally intended to be animated, the `animated` argument was `NO`. Changing the value to `YES` seems to be the solution.

This also seems to have solved some other graphics issues I was experiencing.

Comment: I am fairly baffled as to exactly how and/or why this would affect how button textures are drawn. If anyone else has some insight as to how the two are related, please let me know

Comment: +1 for solving it! I'd like to understand your solution better. There's no UINavigationController in your original question. And a UINavigationController already has a toolbar, so is your "menubar" a *different* toolbar?

Comment: @matt There is no mention of the `UINavigationController`, as that code exists in a separate `UITableViewController` subclass, which functions as the 'level select screen' for the app. The `UIViewController` subclass, the above code exists in, is pushed onto view hierarchy by `UITableViewController` subclass